# Numpy: squaring a large matrix efficiently

Tags: numpy, matrix

I've tried squaring using numpy.square and **2 on a large matrix (16928, 16928), but this very slow, are there any tricks to speed this up? Currently for an array this size, I find ~ 0.8 seconds to be the average running time for **2 (similarly for numpy.square).

Comment: That's about a gigabyte or two of data. It's going to take a while to do anything with that.

Comment: This is straightforward numpy operation.  There aren't any tricks.

Comment: There ARE a lot of tricks speeding things up. Depending on how far you want to go. Matrix multiplication is heavily parallelizable. So, you could try doing that. OpenCL has this as a standard example. But inside numpy I guess that's the most you can get out of it.